# Getting Prop `aria-controls` did not match. error in next.js 13.4.12 and react.js 18.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-dom

I am using the latest Nextjs 13 Version (13.4.12) with React 18.2.0. It's a clean Nextjs project with the new app directory and Tailwind. If I'm using any of the radix-ui primitives I getting the

```
app-index.js:32 Warning: Prop `aria-controls` did not match. Server: "radix-:Rlmcq:" Client: "radix-:R2mpj9:
```

[For references image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwVDz.png)

How to fix this issue?